# Close all submenus at first time

Tags: jquery

I'm using this Jquery code to open/close my submenus :

```
(function() {
    $('#MainMenu > li').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $el = $('ul',this);
        $('#MainMenu > li > ul').not($el).slideUp();
        $el.stop(true, true).slideToggle(400);
    });
    $('#MainMenu > li > ul > li').click(function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
})();
```

---

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-arrow" id="MainMenu">
.
.
.
```

but at the first time (when page is loaded), all submenus are open. 
I want all submenus be closed until user click on menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this following `CSS` to keep all submenus hidden initially.

```
#MainMenu > li > ul {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to use jQuery to hide then use following line on page load.

```
$('#MainMenu > li > ul').hide();
```